# Parallel read from MySql and write into Bigquery using Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The problem statement I'm working on is reading data from MySql on Cloud SQL and splitting it into certain chunks and then writing into BigQuery.

I'm using the below query to create data chunks -

> query = f'SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6....col20 from table
> WHERE MOD(CONV(SUBSTRING(MD5(id), 1, 16), 16, 10),
> {self.num_partitions}) = {hash_value}'

Snippets of the code of Reading from DB and writing into BQ -

```
class ReadFromJdbc(beam.DoFn):  
    def process(self, element):
        # Connecting to MySQL DB
        .......  

        # Replace this with your SQL query
        hash_value = element
        query = f'SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6....col20 from table WHERE MOD(CONV(SUBSTRING(MD5(id), 1, 16), 16, 10), {self.num_partitions}) = {hash_value}'
        # Connection setup
        ......

        try:
            # Create a cursor with fetch_size and execute the query
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            
            # Fetch the results in chunks
            while True:
                results = cursor.fetchmany(self.fetch_size)
                if not results:
                    break
                
                # Yield the results
                yield results
        finally:
            # Close the connection
            connection.close()

# BigQuery output configuration
bigquery_output_config = {
    'project': 'myproject',
    'dataset': 'mydataset',
    'table': 'mytable',
}

class WriteToBigQueryFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, **bigquery_output_config):
        self.bigquery_output_config = bigquery_output_config

def process(self, element):
    table_id = f"{self.bigquery_output_config['project']}:{self.bigquery_output_config['dataset']}.{self.bigquery_output_config['table']}"

    try:
        for record in element:
            yield element
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error processing record: {record}, Error: {e}')
        raise
    logging.info(f'Successfully processed records. Writing to BigQuery: {table_id}')
```

The pipeline options and execution -

```
    # Create a PCollection with a single element
    num_partitions = 10
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
    data = p | 'CreatePartitions' >> beam.Create(range(num_partitions))

    # Apply the pipeline steps using ParDo
    result = (
        data
        | 'Setup JAR' >> beam.ParDo(SetupJAR(jar_gcs_path)) 
        | 'Read From Jdbc' >> beam.ParDo(ReadFromJdbc(fetch_size=1000,num_partitions=num_partitions))
    )

    parallel_write = (
        result 
        | 'TransformAndWriteToBigQuery' >> beam.ParDo(WriteToBigQueryFn(**bigquery_output_config))
        | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=f"{bigquery_output_config['project']}:{bigquery_output_config['dataset']}.{bigquery_output_config['table']}",
            schema='col1:STRING,col2:STRING,col3:DATE,col4:DATE,col5:DATE,col6:STRING,col7:STRING....col20:STRING',
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
        )
    )
    parallel_write = p.run()
    parallel_write.wait_until_finish()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    run()
```

When executing I get the below error, but I'm not able to understand it.

> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py",
> line 603, in __ProcessHttpResponse raise
> exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(
> apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpNotFoundError: HttpError accessing
> https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/alpine-bond-407905/jobs/beam_bq_job_LOAD_AUTOMATIC_JOB_NAME_LOAD_STEP_a06f14a8a92945078e9c4a304de3ce62_677d8f6f2404e51b393d5b653b11bd51_pane0_partition0?alt=json:
> response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type':
> 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Wed, 03 Jan 2024 09:02:08
> GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection':
> '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options':
> 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '404',
> 'content-length': '526', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
>
> "error": {
> "code": 404,   "message": "Not found: Job myproject:beam_bq_job_LOAD_AUTOMATIC_JOB_NAME_LOAD_STEP_a06f14a8a91289078e9c4a094de3ce13_855d8d6d2414e51b393d5j653n11ab51_pane0_partition0",

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more by providing details about your environment(local/cloud)  Also, are you reading and writing from the same project or different ones? If possible  try with a simple query.You can find more details about the error from the logs.